# Deploying a website application done in java on cybera

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have a website that consists of .xml, .jsp, .servlet, .java, persistence and a database. I make a server on Cybera as shown below:

Using username "ubuntu".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-121-generic x86_64)

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Tue Mar 27 18:55:56 UTC 2018

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           83
  Usage of /:   4.5% of 19.65GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 3%                IP address for eth0: 10.1.10.0
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
  https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
  http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

---

### Cloud Image Helper Scripts

To enable automatic updates please run:
/usr/local/bin/enableAutoUpdate

To install the latest OpenStack tools please run:
/usr/local/bin/installOpenStackTools

To use the local software update proxy please run:
/usr/local/bin/localSUS

To remove this message from your message of the day please run:
sudo rm /etc/motd

Last login: Tue Mar 27
ubuntu@kinstance:~$

I am wondering if there is a way to deploy the website using this method. I am still playing around with Cybera to get it running but I thought I could use some guidance if my method is just plain off.

Comment: Do you have war file or jar file with the app?

Comment: If I generate one I put that onto Cybera?

Comment: First you need to install java, then if your app is war you need to install servlet container (tomcat or jetty). If your app is in jar then it probably contains servlet container and You may be able to use 'java -jar yourApp.jar' to start it.